# What is the difference between <xsl:apply-templates /> and <xsl:apply-templates select="." />

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

What is the difference between `<xsl:apply-templates />` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="." />`. I thought that the `select="."` was not necessary, but I am getting different results depending on which I use.

Sorry if this is a repeat. I have tried searching this issue but could not find anything.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation of the differences b/n these two instructions and also for a warning. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What is the difference between
>   `<xsl:apply-templates />` and
>   `<xsl:apply-templates select="." />`

**The first instruction**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

**is a shorthand for**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()" />
```

**The second instruction**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." />
```

**is a shorthand for:**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()" />
```

As we see, **not only these two instructions are different** (the former applies templates to all child nodes and the latter applies templates to the current node), **but the latter is dangerous** and often may lead to an endless loop!

Answer (score 4):

Were you thinking of the difference between

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

and

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
```

? The reason I ask is that `<xsl:apply-templates select="." />` is very uncommon, while `<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />` is very common.

When choosing between these two alternatives, `select="*"` is often unnecessary, but there is a difference:

- As Dimitre pointed out,
  `<xsl:apply-templates />` without a
  select will process *all* child
  nodes. This includes comments,
  processing instructions, and most
  notably, **text** nodes, as well as
  child elements.
- By contrast,  `<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />` will only select child
  **element** nodes.

So if the input XML can have child nodes other than elements, and you don't want to process those nodes, `<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />` is what you want.